# Determining probability that test vector different from reference vector

Tags: probability, vectors, means

I have a reference vector, with a mean and standard deviation for each of its n elements.  I want to compute the probability that a test vector is different than the reference vector.

For a single element, it's easily calculated from the number of standard deviations away from the mean.  How can the probability be calculated for the whole vector?

Context: The vector is energy bins from a radiation spectragram.  The difference is for early detection of the appearance of radioactive isotopes (e.g. in a nuclear power plant) to raise a warning before lethal levels are reached.

Elements in the test and reference vectors rarely are exactly the same, even for a close match, so the joint probability will be near zero over the 3,000 vector elements.  What's needed is some kind of *similarity metric* between the vectors.

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your set-up, but if the elements are independent, that the joint probability would be the product of the individual probabilities, unless there are some additional subtle factors in your problem.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't think the joint probability helps here, e.g. suppose each test element has a 99% chance of matching the reference element (a very close match), and there are 3000 elements.  The joint probability would be on the order of 10 to the -14, essentially zero.  Intuitively this seems like a wrong result for such a close match.